# Color ramps in QGIS has transparency by default?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

I've recently installed QGIS 3.22.10-Białowieża on Ubuntu 22.04.01 jammy and I have a problem with color ramps. When I try to select one of standard color ramp, they are configured with transparency by default (please see the image below).
Does anyone know if is possible to reset color ramps to default values?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have any custom styles (symbols, color ramps...). An easy solution is to search a file in `username/AppData/local/QGIS-##` called `symbology-style.db` and rename it, e.g `symbology-style.db.old`. Reopen QGIS and the defaults styles will be reseted. If it works you can remove the old file.

Comment: thank you very much, it has worked.

Comment: Suddently had the same problem. If you are here and you could not find the file mine was here: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default