# QGIS missing basic symbols for editing lines

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, line, editing

I cannot seem to use/ view any symbols when trying to edit simple lines.
[image: This is what my symbology screen is showing]

I have recently download QGIS 3.28.3-Firenze

I also tried downloading an older version (3.18-Zurich) of the Software and had the same problem.

I tried importing the styles as a .xml from a script provided in another forum. I kept getting a "Incorrect root tag in style: w:wordDocument" so that didn't quite work for me either.

Any ideas on how to get the basic symbology styles onto my QGIS?

Comment: Try [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/439829)  maybe the style database is corrupted.

Comment: If you haven't done any signicant customizations you might delete your QGIS app data folder (C:\Users\yourusernamehere\AppData\Roaming\QGIS) and your current installs, then try a new install.  You don't say but you might indicate what operating system your computer is using and whether you downloaded an install for it directly or via the osgeo4W installer and if the latter whether it was an advanced method or not.